# LED recessed light J-boxes

Tags: electrical

My electrical inspector just failed me because the hidden J-boxes that attach to my 6" LED recessed lights were not mounted to studs. He didn't cite any specific code, so just wondering if this is actually a thing or if more his personal preference.

Answer (score 2):

### You'll need to mount them to *something* substantial

NEC 314.23 requires all junction boxes to be securely and rigidly supported, whether it be by mounting to the face of a wall, attachment to a structural member, "old work" clamps into a finished surface, a pair of rigid conduits, or being embedded into cement or brick.  So, your inspector was bang on in calling out your floppy boxes for a fix, even if they didn't have the Code cite on the tip of their tongue.

Comment: I'm not an electrician, but I'm curious, if a manufacturer takes the same fixture and junction box and certifies the combined thing as an "LED high hat" then it's ok to mount it to a sheetrock ceiling by it's own spring clips, but if you build it yourself the junction box remains subject to mounting requirement?

Comment: Hopefully my electrician can manage to get some screws or something in there, presumably with an extended bit or something, not sure how I'd swing it with just a 6" hole to work with. Boxes weren't floppy per se since there were lots of staples on the cables, but definitely not themselves mounted.

Comment: @jcwkjw20170 -- am I correct in my presumption that there's a length of wiring between the driver-box and the actual LED "puck" that's spring-clipped into the ceiling?

Comment: @jay613 -- what happens is that either the fixture will have the box attached to the LED unit, which is the "spring clips" case, or the fixture will be of the remote-driver type, in which case the driver box needs to be mounted to *something*.  (You could in theory use old-work clips to mount the driver box into the finish ceiling as long as the wiring compartment remand accessible...)

Comment: Thanks.  I had assumed OP's "that attach" meant by screws, not just by wires.  Though now, your earlier question leads me to wonder .... if the ceiling is not yet up, then are the JBs just swinging from the rafters by their cables?  In which case, inspection or not, really?  Or if it is up, and the JBs are, per OP, "hidden", how did the inspector see them?  @jcwkjw20170 can you explain?

Comment: The ceiling is already installed, this is a remodel where new recessed lights were added. The j-box is tucked into the ceiling and there's a low voltage cord (about 6") connecting to the puck. The electrician just tucked the j-boxes back there since he didnt think this was considered "new construction" and says this is the first time an inspector has called him out for not fastening the j-boxes to something.

Answer (score 1):

Boxes that are part of a listed fixture are ok.

The comments sounds like you have separate boxes.

If the box is separate it would be a code violation on the 2020 code if not accessible and mounted.

See NEC 410.118 for a code reference.
Access to other boxes: luminaries recessed in ceilings floors or walls shall not be used to access outlet, pull or junction boxes or conduit bodies unless the box or conduit body is an integral part of the listed luminaire.

If accessible a separate box must be mounted. The old practice of mounting a box next to a recessed fixture was common in the past in many locations as it was not specifically listed as non compliant but the 2020 code eliminates this unless part of the listed fixture (not something we screw to it ourselves unless specifically allowed by the mfg).

So the inspector is not making this up. And the 2020 code is much tougher.