# Are you supposed to mount LED controller/wiring boxes when installing the LED lights

Tags: electrical, wiring, led

I live in Ontario Canada.
When installing these pancake LEDs, you drill the hole into the ceiling drywall, install the wiring into the LED controller box, pop in the light and done.  The LED controller/wiring box has mounting holes but should I use them?
Am I supposed to screw the controller box to a joist? In an earlier post I think it indicated the boxes are supposed to be free floating.  I would prefer to leave them free floating.
So I am trying to find out if I drill a couple holes in a ceiling can I just snake the 14/2 in one end of a joist space and connect to the controllers in a sting down the space? No staples and no mounting the boxes and just install the lights and connect.

- Can someone please clarify?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked this question of my inspector during the pre-inspection and this was his reply.

1. FIRST ***What do the manufactures instructions say?***  So I checked and they were covered by lines 8 and 9.

   8. *New Construction applications*: Junction box shall be firmly secured to studs, joists, or similar fixed structural units.
   9. *Remodel applications*: Do not require the junction box to be firmly secured after the mounting plates, studs, joists, or structural units that have been concealed.  Snap off the junction box tabs, then insert into ceiling.
2. ***He then said that they do not*** require being mounted indicating that the manufactures instructions, in this case, matter.

So in my case and in my location, **it was required that they should NOT** be mounted and that **"I had to have them on a long enough wire to be able to pull the drive box through the light opening for service"**.

Your mileage may vary depending our location regulations or inspector.

Answer (score 4):

They are normally left free floating.  I have never seen it screwed in by an electrician on any of my properties.

And it has always been better this way because the cord on the lights is not very long.  When it comes time to replace the unit which in about 3 years, it makes it easier that the driver is not screwed in.

I have 100+ in my current house and they are not the cheap imports. The first failure was 2 years in, and I get 4-8 failures every year.  Luckily the supplier is still replacing them under warranty.

Apparently, I am not the only one.

> Sealed Units
> The mainstay of LED lights is sealed units, because they are going to last forever. Or as I had thought, 25 years, that is past my lifetime. When they fail, you have to replace the whole light fitting, which is every 3 to 7 years !!!.

From [Are LED Lights really Green ?](https://pacificblue.kiwi/led-lights)

I am not associated with the website.

Comment: Ya this issue really nags me.   You put a dozen of them in a room, one fails in X years. Whatever ... 3, 5, 10, doesn't matter.  At that time you can't buy an exact replica.  Should you buy one or two spares of every type you have?  Or three?   Or when one fails do you accept a mismatch?  Or replace the whole room?  This will become a huge topic of discussion in about 5 years.

Comment: I've been disappointed in LED longevity.  I've put many in my house just a few years ago and they are already failing.   They were marketed to last 20 years....now barely better than incandescent.

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to use approved equipment (UL, ETL or CSA) equipment - NEC 110.2. Many of the "specials" on eBay and Amazon Marketplace are cheap, unsafe and illegal.   The one in your first photo is legit; the second one I cannot tell.

Once you have approved equipment, you are assured labeling and instructions have also been approved, and you must follow those (NEC 110.2).  The method described in the instructions is approved, and if it doesn't require anchoring, then it's not required.

Comment: My inspector concurs and in my particular case, "Not mounting" was not only accepted but suggested so I could bull the boxes through the light hole for service.

Answer (score 0):

The holes in the boxes are for convenience. Yes you can leave the boxes loose and the cable does not have to be stapled when run through an existing wall or ceiling.  The cable does have to have insulation and strain protection where it enters the box.

Comment: There was a similar question this week about a major renovation.  Ceiling wide open.  When you do the rough-in can you leave the box dangling from an unstapled 2-foot loop of cable?  The instructions for the listed device say "yes", I think that's the key.

Comment: The requirements for mounting junction boxes, including wiring compartments inside devices, fed by standard permanent house wiring are clear in the electrical codes, and nothing suggested by fixture manufacturers or typical practice by installers can overrule them.

Comment: I have the instructions provided by the manufacture and they indicate that new construction requires mounting.  Remodel does NOT require mounting of the driver box in Ontario.

Answer (score -1):

The question of whether those separate LED fixture controller boxes need to be mounted has been answered at [LED recessed light J-boxes](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/218575/led-recessed-light-j-boxes) and the answer is YES.

Comment: kreemoweet according to the Manufacter the answer is only correct if this is a new home install.  The instructions provided by the manufacture indicate that a remodel does NOT require mounting of the driver box in Ontario.

Comment: @Bmac - Manufacturer has no authority to modify or invalidate any requirement set forth in governing electrical codes. I do not know what your local codes may require (or what some individual inspector may claim) but any place in the US that has adopted the relevant unmodified sections of the NEC requires junction boxes to be fixed in place in some fashion, and any NMC wiring entering it to be secured within 8 or 12 inches. Any manufacturer statements to the contrary are simply irrelevant.